# Question: How do I export a C# ListView Winform control to a Microsoft Excel Workbook

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, listview, export

I came to SO looking for a generic solution to export a ListView control to a Microsoft Excel Workbook with a single sheet

Notes

1. I want to configure number of sheets in a new workbook to 1
2. I want to tell excel that cell recalculation is manual.

I found a few potential partial solutions.  I didn't find anything I found useful as a starting point.

I am answering my own question.  Thanks and I hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

`using System;
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    // Add a COM reference to "Microsoft Excel ##.# Object"
    static class ExportListView
    {
        static public bool ExportToExcel(ListView lv, bool bColHdr = true)
        {
            bool bRet = true;
            try
            {
                Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oXL;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook oWB;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet oSheet;

                try
                {
                    oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application { SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1 };
                    oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value);
                    oXL.Calculation = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlCalculation.xlCalculationManual;
                    oSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)oWB.Sheets[1];

                    int iCol = -1;
                    for (iCol = 1; iCol <= lv.Columns.Count && bColHdr; iCol++)
                        oSheet.Cells[1, iCol] = lv.Columns[iCol - 1].Text;
                    for (int iRow = 1; iRow <= lv.Items.Count; iRow++)
                    {
                        for (iCol = 1; iCol <= lv.Items[iRow - 1].SubItems.Count; iCol++)
                            oSheet.Cells[bColHdr ? iRow + 1 : iRow, iCol] = lv.Items[iRow - 1].SubItems[iCol - 1].Text;
                    }

                    try { oWB.Worksheets[1].Delete(); } catch { Console.WriteLine("Error Deleting Sheet1"); }
                    for (int iSheet = 1; iSheet <= oWB.Sheets.Count; iSheet++)
                        oWB.Sheets[iSheet].Columns.AutoFit();
                    oWB.Worksheets[1].Activate();

                    oXL.Visible = true;
                    oXL.UserControl = true;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    bRet = false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
            finally
            {
                Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
            }
            return bRet;
        }
    }`